# React - one or many stores

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

When using React and following Flux, what is the best approach for managing state in stores, a single store that rules them all or at the other end of the spectrum a store per entity?

Implementation is intended for an enterprise eccommerce app, so pretty big and complicated!

Comment: Depends really. I have answered similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33111552/5358807). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your requirements to use #flux are already set, but over some time *"Redux turned out to be the better Flux"*. If you haven't started yet, have a look on [Redux](http://redux.js.org/).

Regarding [Stores](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Store.html), they have a clear statement here:

> It’s important to note that you’ll only have a single store in a Redux
>   application. When you want to split your data handling logic, you’ll
>   use reducer composition instead of many stores.

So they have a good receipe to solve a problem you might be facing right now when doing classic Flux.

But also, sorry for not answering your question ;)